# How to import a large json file with gridfs to mongodb directly with schema ready

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

Normally we can use the command **mongoimport** from the shell to upload JSON files and **Large** ones also to mongodb and we would have our schema ready in the collection without the need to worry about the max size (16MB) as mongo will take care of the batch size etc ( this has been tested and worked), and data would be in rows and everything is great.

The main problem here is how to do the same thing with python by using pymongo and GridFS. When I am using GridFS, it is uploading to a different type of collection (*.files) and schema is not defined like the 1st method. Files are in bytes and collections names are *.files

I would like to know how to do the python method and get the results as with using mongoimport command

My code is :

```
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db, collection='test_collection')
with open(path_to_big_json_file, 'rb') as dictionary:
    fs.put(dictionary, filename='test_filename')
```

and the results are as below:

[image]

**My goal** is to have immediately the schema ready in a normal collection and not in a GridFS collection like that: 
[image]

I have tried bulk insert in pymongo and it hasn't worked as the file was so large,
I am sure that there would we a way, it is not necessary to use GridFS, but let's keep it in python

Thank you!

Comment: `db.append(file.read_contents('path/to/file'), is_large_file=True, use_multi_cores=True)`??

Comment: I haven't found an append function for db, and the others don't exist as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have created a function that splits the dataframe and saves them temporarily in order to insert it later

It works on scaling each dataframe to parts to less than the 16 MB by 10percent, then we ingest that

P.S: It's for GeoJSON

```
def insert_geojson_in_batches_to_mongo(mongoclient, db, collection_name, origin_path, threshold=10):

  df = gpd.read_file(transformed_path)
  file_size = os.path.getsize(origin_path)
  max_size = mongoclient.max_bson_size
  number_of_dataframes = ceil(file_size*(1+threshold/100) / max_size)
  df_len = len(df)
  number_of_rows_per_df = floor(df_len/number_of_dataframes)
  collection = db.get_collection(collection_name)

  with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
    count = 0
    k = 0
    while True:
      if count > df_len-1:
            break          
      filename = tmpdirname + 'df' + str(count) + '.geojson'
      start = count
      count += number_of_rows_per_df  
      k += 1
      df.iloc[start : count].to_file(filename, driver="GeoJSON")      
      with open(filename) as f: 
        data = json.load(f)  
      data = data['features']
      print('bulk {0}/{1} is being loaded'.format(k , number_of_dataframes+1))
      collection.insert_many(data)
```